# Save checkbox UI after other component render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a multi-step form in React which every question is a component. 
on the parent component, I have the state. 
on the first component, I have a question with a checkbox that when I check the option I push it to an array on the state.
when I moved to the next question and go back to the previous question the check mark is gone but the state is still updated.

I can't figure on how to control the checked value of every checkbox.

I've created a codesand for my case
https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-sky-clxeo

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a checked property in your input like the following:

```
<input
   type="checkbox"
   name={checkbox}
   value={checkbox}
   onChange={handleCheckbox}
   checked={properties.includes(checkbox)}
/>
```

Comment: oh this is sucks I wrote this line checked={properties.includes({ checkbox })} on my local :( Thanks!!!!